# Single MySQL Query on multiple databases

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, database-connection

I am working with the following set-up:

Consider two MySQL databases: `abc`and `xyz`, each with their own table:`abc`.`table_in_abc` and `xyz`.`table_in_xyz`. I need to run a simple MySQL query that select elements from the `table_in_abc` with a JOIN relationship to `table_in_xyz`.

In Workbench, the following query works fine:

```
SELECT AB.* , XY.*
FROM `abc`.`table_in_abc` AB
LEFT JOIN `xyz`.`table_in_xyz` XY ON AB.`ID` = XY`ID`
```

I am trying to achieve the same things in VBA. I am able to run a MySQL query on a single database (see example below) but unable to do so when the query involves multiple databases.

Example of simple VBA query on single database:

```
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver}" _
& ";SERVER=" & server_name _
& ";DATABASE=" & database_name _
& ";UID=" & user_id _
& ";PWD=" & password _
& ";OPTION=3" '

Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM `abc`.`table_in_abc` WHERE `ID`=" & ID & ";" 
rs1.Open sqlstr, conn, adOpenStatic
With Worksheets("Main").Cells(a, 1)
.ClearContents
.CopyFromRecordset rs1
End With
rs1.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing
```

Comment: Are those databases in the same MySQL instance? Also could you add your VBA code where you did do a `LEFT JOIN` command and what error you got back? I've run into trouble in the past with my data types for running queries getting truncated. Try doing a break and confirm your query string.

Comment: Also note that on your Workbench example you use `AB` and `XY` rather than `abc` and `xyz`. Is this just a typo or could it be the reason for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve my above problem by simply setting two connections to the two different databases (working on the same MySQL instance).

My code looks like that :

```
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver}" _
& ";SERVER=" & server_name _
& ";DATABASE=" & database_name _
& ";UID=" & user_id _
& ";PWD=" & password _
& ";OPTION=3" '

Set conn2 = New ADODB.Connection
conn2.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver}" _
& ";SERVER=" & server_name _
& ";DATABASE=" & database_name2 _
& ";UID=" & user_id2 _
& ";PWD=" & password2 _
& ";OPTION=3" '

' SELECT Query with LEFT JOIN on the two different databases
Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
sqlstr = "SELECT AB.* , XY.* FROM `abc`.`table_in_abc` AB LEFT JOIN `xyz`.`table_in_xyz` XY ON AB.`ID` = XY`ID`"
rs1.Open sqlstr, conn, adOpenStatic
With Worksheets("main").Cells(1, 1)
.ClearContents
.CopyFromRecordset rs1
End With
rs1.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing
```